# How to change the color of scroll bar in table widget in PyQt5 Python

Tags: python, colors, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I am working on designing the UI in which I have a `table widget` where I am showing some data. It looks like below:

[image]

As of now the scroll bar of the table widget takes the background color of widget due to which its not visible at first sight. Is it possible to change its color so that it more visible. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How scroll bars are drawn completely depends on the QStyle.

A possibility could be to set the palette for the scroll bar, using the correct [ColorRole](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum), but unfortunately not all styles draw widgets in the same way. Some use the `QPalette.Button` role, others completely ignore the widget palette at all.

While a QProxyStyle could be used, some styles also ignore the `CE_ScrollBarSlider` control as they completely draw the whole scroll bar on their own.

For the default "windows" style, though, the proxy style usually works:

```
class ProxyStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def drawControl(self, ctl, opt, qp, widget=None):
        if ctl == self.CE_ScrollBarSlider:
            opt = opt.__class__(opt)
            opt.palette.setColor(opt.palette.Button, QtCore.Qt.green)
        super().drawControl(ctl, opt, qp, widget)

# ...

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle(ProxyStyle(app.style()))
```

Note that this will set the style for the *whole* application. If you want to use this behavior only for a single tablewidget, you need to set the style individually for *both* scroll bars (as styles are not propagated to children).

```
class TableWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        style = ProxyStyle(self.style().objectName())
        self.horizontalScrollBar().setStyle(style)
        self.verticalScrollBar().setStyle(style)
```

As you can see, in the example above I used a different constructor. That's because using `ProxyStyle(QStyle)` results in the proxy *overriding* the style in the constructor (so you would end up having all scroll bars painted with the proxy style anyway). Using `self.style().objectName()` ensures that a new style will be created and that style will only be used for the proxy, thus for the widgets it's applied onto.

Finally, if you need to provide cross platform (and cross style) compatibility, the only possible solution is to use stylesheets, for which you should read [customizing QScrollBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qscrollbar). Note that when setting stylesheets on scroll bars you cannot set properties for single controls (like only for the buttons, or the handle): you *must* provide the stylesheet for every control, otherwise the scrollbar won't be drawn correctly and it might become unusable.